# How to convert HTML content to string in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am building an application using [cakephp v4](https://cakephp.org/).

Should save JSON object including HTML content type while creating an event in [MS graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview).

[image]

```
$description = '<span class="is-size-6" style="font-style: normal; font-weight: 400;">Microsoft Teams Meeting</span><span style="font-style: normal; font-weight: 400;"></span><div class="is-flex is-flex-direction-column mt-3"><span style="font-weight: 700;">The meeting url will be added here.</span><a href="https://aka.ms/JoinTeamsMeeting" target="_blank">Learn More</a></div>';

$event = '{
  "subject": "Hello World",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "' . h($description) . '",
  },
  ...
}';
```

If I fetch the saved event, then the body->content looks like:

```
<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta content=\"text/html; charset=us-ascii\">\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n&lt;span class=&quot;is-size-6&quot; style=&quot;font-style: normal; font-weight: 400;&quot;&gt;Microsoft Teams Meeting&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-style: normal; font-weight: 400;&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;is-flex is-flex-direction-column mt-3&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight: 700;&quot;&gt;The meeting url\r\n will be added here.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://aka.ms/JoinTeamsMeeting&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;Learn More&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

I want to show the HTML content in textarea element.

What I tried is to use php [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function.

But it still has HTML tags like the following image.

[image]

How to show only strings like the first image?

Comment: 1. Don't `htmlentities`  2. Don't put it in a `textarea`.

Comment: Then what should I do now? The body content should able to edit and update.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're doing but if you just echo HTML the browser will render HTML.

Comment: I can't echo because handling the body content part to show is in js file.